# Recent change in userid on stackoverflow

Tags: support, profile-page, data-explorer, user-accounts

I clearly remember my user ID was **1310070** few days back and my profile link was

> https://stackoverflow.com/users/1310070/blunderboy

But recently I observed this link gives me 404 and my profile link has been transferred to

> https://stackoverflow.com/users/816213/blunderboy

This means my userId has also been changed. Few questions in my mind:

1. Why did the user IDs change? They were supposed to be unique.
2. Is there any way I can see which user IDs changed or did it happen to all users?

I built a chrome extension [StackEye - which allows to follow other users/questions](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stackeye/pihfndpmcafdecheofkjfkadecoogigm). It works on userIds and data is stored in localStorage. Now all the extension users might have followed some users on StackExchange sites and now they won't be getting notification of questions/answers because user IDs have changed or they might be getting wrong data.

What should I do in this case?

Comment: Hmm, the working url is a smaller number. Did you by chance create an account looong ago and now they just happened to get merged?

Comment: Did you perhaps log in differently from the normal way you normally do, or try to add another login option (which may have triggered the merge with your older forgotten-about account)?

Comment: @jmort253 Nopes..none of my account got merged..I will be pretty happy if this happened only to me.Atleast StackEye users won't get frustated ;) apart from the one who were following me :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did end up with two profiles that were merged on April 7. There's not much more to say about that except that I'm very certain that they were both yours.

Our login/signup system is a bit convoluted, and it's not uncommon for folks to end up with two profiles once in a while, if they forget what they signed in with once upon a time.

There's nothing else for you to do - just relax, enjoy your profile with the lower userid, and  remember to sign in with the same credentials going forward just in case.

Comment: Oh..Thanks Anna for the information :)